# Jquery Select2 4.0 Bootstrap Styling

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-select2

I am using Select2 in a project, its styling sticks out like a sore thumb from other bootstrap(ed) components. Personally I like the way select2 looks but need to create consistency. In earlier versions I have used select2 boostrap css 3 from [here](https://fk.github.io/select2-bootstrap-css/)

This doesnt work on Select2 4.0, anyone has any ideas or hints ? At the very least, I would like to adjust the height of Select2.

Much appreciated...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just use a regular select2 from https://select2.github.io/examples.html and override the style with `!important` declaration, for example

```
.select2-container .select2-selection--single {height: 50px !important;}
```

Comment: Thanks, worked as advertised.